# Could I use LDA (Linear discriminant analysis) for outlier detection?

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

Could I use LDA method to separate outlier from major points?

I want to find outlier from certain data with LDA, but I couldn't find use of LDA for outlier detection.

Basically I want do the work like below :

[image: example of outlier detection]

I'm going to try with `MASS:lda()` package function.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, also not the purpose of LDA.